# Field Medic OS Crash 00000175 reboot

Tags: windows-10-mobile, lock-screen, system-apps, lumia-550

I bought Lumia 550 with Windows Phone 10 1,5 month ago.

And have a trouble with a phone, after unlocking, sometimes it reboots (I think something causes OS to crash), it often 10 or more times a day, depending on usage.

I downloaded [Field Medic](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/store/apps/Field-Medic/9WZDNCRFJB82) application and found reports of OS crashes(OS crash 00000175).

I tried everything from removing the SD card to hard resetting and Windows Device Recovery Tool. Nothing helped.

What do you think about OS crash 00000175 and what can I do other than going to service center?

Comment: What do you mean when you say you "unblocked" the phone?

Comment: Also, have you tried a soft/hard reset?

Comment: @RowlandShaw Yes, i tried both, hard and soft reset.
Unblock means press unlock button and enter PIN, but sometimes i can't enter pin because os crashes and reboot =)

Comment: Have you checked for any available updates? Are you running an insider build at all?

Comment: @RowlandShaw, installed latest available update for common users.

Comment: Have you tried Stop restart app? That worked for me....http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/questions/13579/lumia-535-restarts-by-itself

Comment: @User5 I though yes, and I think it was hardware problem