# Lumia 535 restarts by itself

Tags: nokia-lumia-535

I newly migrated from android plateform to windows and my lumia 535 eventually stops everything in between and reboots by itself even when I am playing some audio or video. How can it be fixed?

Comment: Is it a new phone or second hand phone? If possible try hard resetting it & after that install all system updates.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We identified a problem in some versions of Windows Phone 8.1 that could cause a phone to restart periodically. We've already made a fix that has resolved this problem for the majority of Windows Phones. However, some phones that have not connected to Microsoft servers still need the fix to be applied.

First, check to see if you have an update available. Go to the App list, tap Settings Settings Icon ﻿> Phone update, and then tap Check for updates. If there is an update available, install the update.

***To check and fix your phone using an app***

1. Download the [Stop Restart app](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/store/apps/stop-restart-app/9nblggh30xlk) to your phone, open it, and then follow the  steps in the app. (For best results, connect to Wi-Fi.)
2. The app will display either of two results:

   - **Your phone is OK**. Your phone is fixed, and you don't need to do anything else.
   - **We need to fix your phone**. Follow the "To fix your phone using a PC" steps in this topic if the app wasn't able to do so.

> Note :
>   Even if the app fixes your phone or says your phone is OK, you may still be offered a critical update.

***To fix your phone using a PC***

1. Make sure that:

   - Your phone's battery is completely charged.
   - You don't disconnect or use your phone while the fix is running.
2. Connect your phone with a USB cable to a PC that is connected to the Internet.
3. Unlock your phone if you have set a lock screen password.
   4.On your PC, run Microsoft Fix it Solution—Stop Phone Restart.
4. Leave your phone turned on and connected while the fix runs. During the process the phone will restart and display spinning gears with a progress bar. It should take a few minutes for the process to complete.
5. When the process is complete, your phone will be fixed and display the message "Update successful."
6. Tap **All done**.

Source - [Link](https://support.microsoft.com/en-in/help/12626/windows-phone-stop-my-phone-from-restarting)

Comment: But for doing this Mobile phone should have on. my phone continuously restarting . in this condition what i supposed to do ?